# Liveness and Readiness probe failed: context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ngrok

## Issue Solved

I'm trying to use ngrok ingress controller from [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/docs/using-ngrok-with/k8s/) to expose my nodejs deployment.

I have the followed the above guide to integrate ngrok ingress controller with my deployment to expose it. However I ran into an issue where Liveness and Readiness probe failed and after awhile the pod status will show CrashLoopBackOff. This happens after I run the helm install command from the ngrok guide. I'm not too sure if its a firewall issue or is it something else.

The follwing will show the errors outputs and an attachment of my manifest.yaml file

```
$ kubectl get all -n pi-deploy

NAME                                                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
pod/website-deploy-0                                                  1/1     Running   0             46m
pod/ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-man4vf2z   0/1     Running   1 (59s ago)   2m1s

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/website-deploy   ClusterIP   10.43.1.91   <none>        80/TCP    46m

NAME                                                                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-manager   0/1     1            0           2m1s

NAME                                                                                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-manager-7c6f4cf67d   1         1         0       2m1s

NAME                              READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/website-deploy   1/1     46m
```

```
$ kubectl describe pod/ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-man4vf2z -n pi-deploy

NAME                                                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
pod/website-deploy-0                                                  1/1     Running   0             47m
pod/ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-man4vf2z   0/1     Running   3 (15s ago)   3m17s

NAME                     TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/website-deploy   ClusterIP   10.43.1.91   <none>        80/TCP    47m

NAME                                                                             READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-manager   0/1     1            0           3m17s

NAME                                                                                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-manager-7c6f4cf67d   1         1         0       3m18s

NAME                              READY   AGE
statefulset.apps/website-deploy   1/1     47m
                                                                                                                    
┌──(cyrof㉿kali)-[~]
└─$ kubectl describe pod/ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-man4vf2z -n pi-deploy
Name:             ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-man4vf2z
Namespace:        pi-deploy
Priority:         0
Service Account:  ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller
Node:             knode1/192.168.86.31
Start Time:       Sun, 23 Jul 2023 23:17:47 +0800
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                  app.kubernetes.io/instance=ngrok-ingress-controller
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=kubernetes-ingress-controller
                  pod-template-hash=7c6f4cf67d
Annotations:      prometheus.io/path: /metrics
                  prometheus.io/port: 8080
                  prometheus.io/scrape: true
Status:           Running
IP:               10.42.1.91
IPs:
  IP:           10.42.1.91
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-manager-7c6f4cf67d
Containers:
  ngrok-ingress-controller:
    Container ID:  containerd://e1affe57cc4756ed15e417e712c0814fdf29ef7139903162613fba1736aa1d77
    Image:         docker.io/ngrok/kubernetes-ingress-controller:0.8.0
    Image ID:      docker.io/ngrok/kubernetes-ingress-controller@sha256:ca189da6c28d02a6480ad8dbb615df7609fa08445aebf026ff1e6a46ec267540
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /manager
    Args:
      --controller-name=k8s.ngrok.com/ingress-controller
      --zap-log-level=info
      --zap-stacktrace-level=error
      --zap-encoder=json
      --health-probe-bind-address=:8081
      --metrics-bind-address=:8080
      --election-id=ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-leader
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 23 Jul 2023 23:20:49 +0800
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    2
      Started:      Sun, 23 Jul 2023 23:19:49 +0800
      Finished:     Sun, 23 Jul 2023 23:20:49 +0800
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  3
    Liveness:       http-get http://:8081/healthz delay=15s timeout=1s period=20s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:8081/readyz delay=5s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      NGROK_API_KEY:    <set to the key 'API_KEY' in secret 'ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-credentials'>    Optional: false
      NGROK_AUTHTOKEN:  <set to the key 'AUTHTOKEN' in secret 'ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-credentials'>  Optional: false
      POD_NAMESPACE:    pi-deploy (v1:metadata.namespace)
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-jgng5 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             False 
  ContainersReady   False 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-jgng5:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                    From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                   ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  3m23s                  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned pi-deploy/ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-man4vf2z to knode1
  Normal   Killing    2m22s                  kubelet            Container ngrok-ingress-controller failed liveness probe, will be restarted
  Warning  Unhealthy  2m21s                  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.42.1.91:8081/readyz": read tcp 10.42.1.1:59128->10.42.1.91:8081: read: connection reset by peer
  Normal   Pulled     2m21s (x2 over 3m22s)  kubelet            Container image "docker.io/ngrok/kubernetes-ingress-controller:0.8.0" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    2m21s (x2 over 3m22s)  kubelet            Created container ngrok-ingress-controller
  Normal   Started    2m21s (x2 over 3m21s)  kubelet            Started container ngrok-ingress-controller
  Warning  Unhealthy  102s (x5 over 3m2s)    kubelet            Liveness probe failed: Get "http://10.42.1.91:8081/healthz": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
  Warning  Unhealthy  92s (x12 over 3m12s)   kubelet            Readiness probe failed: Get "http://10.42.1.91:8081/readyz": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

```
$ kubectl logs pod/ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-man4vf2z -n pi-deploy

{"level":"info","ts":"2023-07-23T15:21:49Z","logger":"setup","msg":"starting manager","version":"0.8.0","commit":"2d38bc7e6cbc1e413f6d75a7e15e781242c7674f"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-07-23T15:21:50Z","logger":"controller-runtime.metrics","msg":"Metrics server is starting to listen","addr":":8080"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-07-23T15:21:50Z","logger":"setup","msg":"found matching ingress","ingress-name":"website-deploy-ingress","ingress-namespace":"pi-deploy"}
```

This is my manifest.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: website-deploy
  namespace: pi-deploy
spec:
  # type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: website-deploy
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: website-deploy
  namespace: pi-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: website-deploy
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: website-deploy
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Always
      containers:
        - name: backend
          image: cyrof/pi_website_docker:master
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
          envFrom:
            - secretRef:
                name: pi-env
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health-check
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 15
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 3
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health-check
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 3
          startupProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health-check
              port: 8080
            initialDelaySeconds: 60
            periodSeconds: 10
            timeoutSeconds: 5
            failureThreshold: 3
      dnsPolicy: None
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers: ["8.8.8.8"]
        searches:
          - default.svc.cluster.local
          - svc.cluster.local
          - cluster.local
        options:
          - name: ndots
            value: "2"
---
# ngrok Ingress Controller Configuration
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: website-deploy-ingress
  namespace: pi-deploy
spec:
  ingressClassName: ngrok
  rules:
    - host: 9f3122c8f71c-10425669031728034697.ngrok-free.app
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: website-deploy
                port:
                  number: 80
```

I tried to increase the timeout for the liveness and readiness probes but to no avial. I'm really in a pinch here on how to go about it.

```
helm install ngrok-ingress-controller ngrok/kubernetes-ingress-controller \
  --namespace ngrok-ingress-controller \
  --create-namespace \
  --set credentials.apiKey=$NGROK_API_KEY \
  --set credentials.authtoken=$NGROK_AUTHTOKEN \
  --set tunner.timeout=60s
```

## Update

I think its a dns issue. When i remove this part of the code my website-deploy pod also gives the same error as the ingress controller. Is there a way to make this part of the code global instead of specifying each pod?

```
dnsPolicy: None
      dnsConfig:
        nameservers: ["8.8.8.8"]
        searches:
          - default.svc.cluster.local
          - svc.cluster.local
          - cluster.local
        options:
          - name: ndots
            value: "2"
```

## Solved

I manage to fix the issue by configuring coredns to make nameserver to 8.8.8.8 instead of the default which fix my error.
Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: In order to debug, You can exec into the pod using `kubectl exec -it ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-man4vf2z -n pi-deploy -- /bin/sh`

When you are in the pod, try to curl/wget `localhost:8081/healthz` and
`localhost:8081/readyz` and see response. If there is no response/error, that means the problem is in the configuration of the pod.  If there is a response, then there could be some networking problem, then needs to be checked in some other way

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment @saurabh_garg. However when i try 
`kubectl exec -it ngrok-ingress-controller-kubernetes-ingress-controller-man4vf2z -n pi-deploy -- /bin/sh` 
It returns 
`error: Internal error occurred: error executing command in container: failed to exec in container: failed to start exec "19dfbe76564dbe1aae2054eca77eac119cf0f2a3c4d68f0c96804da8c307002a": OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: unable to start container process: exec: "/bin/sh": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory: unknown`

Comment: So it seems that by the time, you run exec, the pods readiness, startupProbe already failed the pod. Try disabling them once and see if you can exec into pod

Comment: After disabling the Probes, I tried the command again and got this `$ curl localhost:8081/healthz
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8081 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server`
`$ curl localhost:8081/readyz
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8081 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server

`